# Checking if a static variable is Null after setting it to null

Tags: php, oop, variables, scope, null

Recently, when I was downloading an OpenSource project, I came accross this PHP code:

```
<?php

namespace That\Thing;

final class Somewhere
{
  //...

  public static function somefunc( /*...*/ )
  {
    static $exists = null;
    if ($exists === null) {
      $exists = \function_exists('mb_substr');
    }

    if ($exists) {
      //...
```

My PHP is OK, so reading the above, it puzzled me what `static $exists = null` precisely does? It did not make sense to me to set a variable to Null, then immediately check if the variable is actually Null? (Add Duhh here)

Is there some sort of PHP version checking going on here? Why would someone write this code?

I have included the surrounding OOP, in case it has an influence. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static` persists the variable value across function calls. But, `static` variables can only be initialised with constant values. *This* is not supported (function call in static initialiser):

```
static $exists = \function_exists('mb_substr');
```

So as a workaround for this the variable is initialised to `null`, then if the value is `null` (if it's the first time the variable is accessed, right after initialisation), it's set to its actual value.

---

`static` values are initialised in the compilation stage, before runtime. Hence no runtime function can be called or other overly complex runtime calculation can be done at that time. `static $exists = null` happens at compile time; then the first time the function is called, a runtime calculation is done.

Comment: So why doesn't PHP compile `static $exists = \function_exists('mb_substr');` automatically into `static $exists = null; $exists = \function_exists('mb_substr');`, if the problem is to use constants at compile time? Or is this particular structure intended as a 'caching' design (check for `\function_exists('mb_substr')` once, and store the result (true or false but not Null) if this function gets reused?

Comment: Well, it doesn't. And yes, it's supposed to be a "cache" and save the overhead of the repeated function call.